# notifyItemRemoved() from non Ui Thread not working in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to remove item from list and `notifyItemRemoved()` method it is not working it gives array index out of bound exception by removing last item and if I remove item from middle its also remove very next item to it but if put the code outside the thread its working fine 
there is my code

```
       Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int progress = 0;
            ArrayList<MediaFileObject> selection = localDatabase.getAllMediaObjectsOfID(list.get(selectedAlbum).getId());
            for (MediaFileObject obj : selection) {
                if (searializeableTasks.isCancelled())
                    break;
                localDatabase.moveMediaObjectToTrash(obj);
                progress++;
                if (searializeableTasks.isCancelled())
                    sendProgressToHandle(-101);
                else
                    sendProgressToHandle(progress);
            }
            if (!searializeableTasks.isCancelled())
                localDatabase.deleteAlbum(list.get(selectedAlbum).getId());

            Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    list.remove(selectedAlbum);
                    savedAlbumAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedAlbum);

                }
            });


        }
    };

    searializeableTasks.startTasks(localDatabase.getAllMediaObjectsOfID(list.get(selectedAlbum).getId()).size(), runnable);
```

but if put all this code inside main thread(Class) its working fine as expected I am putting my code here I want to show my custom progress dialog there for after completion I want to update my `RecyclerView` can someone please help me. What is wrong in my code? or Why it is not working in separate thread?

Comment: use only  `notifyDataSetChanged();`  It will work.

Comment: currently i am doing this 
`Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); handler.post(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { Log.e("sizes4",list.size()+""+savedAlbumAdapter.getItemCount‌​()); list.clear(); list.addAll(localDatabase.getAllAlbums()); savedAlbumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } });`

Answer (score 2):

Call notify on main thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            savedAlbumAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedAlbum);
        }
    });
```

**Or**

```
 yourrecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            savedAlbumAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedAlbum);
        }
    });
```

Comment: currently i am doing this
  `Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("sizes4",list.size()+""+savedAlbumAdapter.getItemCount());
                        list.clear();
                        list.addAll(localDatabase.getAllAlbums());
                        savedAlbumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }); `

Comment: Do i have to remove the item from the local list too like this? 
`list.remove(selectedAlbum);`

Comment: No . Only for Ui operations.

Comment: Sir its working fine but animation is not working :(
but i put the same code outside the thread animation is also working fine

Answer (score -1):

use only

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It will work.If you use `notifyItemRemoved()` after `remove()` then it would again try to remove next position , so `Exception` arises.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of notifyDataSetChanged? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged() `If you are writing an adapter it will always be more efficient to use the more specific change events if you can. Rely on notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort.`

Comment: currently i am doing this but animation does not work on this method and its reloads all items again

Comment: ok then use only `notifyItemRemoved()`.  And use it in UI thread

Comment: Do i have to remove the item from the local list in fragment like this? `list.remove(selectedAlbum); `

Comment: `if(list.size > 0){
    list.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}` use this.